# Issues connecting to RabbitMQ from an Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, rabbitmq

I have a simple Azure function triggered by HTTP-posts.
The payload should then be forwarded to RabbitMQ.

I'm using the C# RabbitMQ.Client libraries.

However when I call the CreateConnection() method from the ConnectionFactory class, I get an error that the endpoint could not be reach. The stack trace shows that the RabbitMQ client libraries cannot find assembly System.Threading.Channels:

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
[2023-04-14T09:23:45.676Z]  ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Channels, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
[2023-04-14T09:23:45.676Z] 
[2023-04-14T09:23:45.676Z] File name: 'System.Threading.Channels, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
[2023-04-14T09:23:45.676Z]    at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection..ctor(ConnectionFactory factory, String clientProvidedName)
[2023-04-14T09:23:45.676Z]    at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
[2023-04-14T09:23:45.676Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2023-04-14T09:23:45.676Z]    at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
```

- I've tried different RabbitMQ servers and they all work from other services, but the Azure functions seems to fail for other reasons.
- I've also tried to install the System.Threading.Channels from NuGet.
- I've tried running the Azure function as standalone, within a Docker Compose, and from the Azure cloud to a public RabbitMQ server.

This is the part of the code that fails (values changed to hide the real values).

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
{
   Uri = new Uri("amqp://user:pass@localhost:5672/vhost"),
};
```

And this is where the error is thrown:

```
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
```

Comment: I maintain the RabbitMQ.Client library. I don't know anything about Azure functions. Is there some sort of "setup" step where packages are restored? Can you select what version of the runtime you are using?

Comment: Thanks Luke, I might have found the issue and it doesn't seem related to the RabbitMQ.Client library. The issue seems to be that the Azure function templates of Visual studio 2022 uses and older version of RabbitMQ library (5.1.2) while my referenced projects use the latest 6.5 version.