# RabbitMQ throws exception when creating connection

Tags: rabbitmq

I am currently trying to implement rabbitMQ, but when trying to create a connection I get the following error:

> Executed 'GS1Fetcher' (Failed,
> Id=4c77f28d-12e0-4a71-a9d3-69e38d41564d, Duration=137ms)
> [2023-06-21T17:15:39.447Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while
> executing function: GS1Fetcher. RabbitMQ.Client: None of the specified
> endpoints were reachable. RabbitMQ.Client: Could not load file or
> assembly 'System.Threading.Channels, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.

RabbitMQ is running locally in a docker container. I checked if the required port (5672) is open, which according to my findings is open only under 5674, but that must be no problem right? The way I checked this is by running docker ps in my windows command prompt. Which resulted in the following;

| CONTAINER ID | IMAGE | COMMAND | PORTS | NAMES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 38fc3c343af4 | rabbitmq:management-alpine | "docker-entrypoint.s…" | 4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 15671/tcp, 15691-15692/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15672->15672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5674->5672/tcp | trusting_keldysh |

The code sammple below shows my code implementation. This is an Azure function using .NET 6

```
_factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
_factory.UserName = "****";
_factory.Password = "****";
_factory.Port = 5674;
_conn = _factory.CreateConnection();
```

I am left dumbfound what I can still do to fix this exception. Are my findings that the port are open incorrect? is there some other setting/configuration for docker that I missed? Or did I miss some configuration on the rabbitMQ side

Answer (score 4):

I have found the answer to why this error occured.
It seems that the rabbitMQ nugetpackage with version 6.5.0 has no backwards compatability (which was the version I was using).

So if you are using .NET 6 or below. Make use a rabbitMQ Nugetpackage version lower then 6.5.0. For .NET 7 you can use package version 6.5.0.

They have updated one of their dependencies in version 6.5.0 'System.Threading.Channels' to 7.0.0 from 4.7.1. The former is not available in .NET 6 hence I get the error that occured

Thanks to this post for nudging my collegue and I in the right direction [Issues connecting to RabbitMQ from an Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76013632/issues-connecting-to-rabbitmq-from-an-azure-function)